# MeteorJS.On refreshing a page the search results get lost

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I am using a searchbox for my webapp.On clicking the search button the user gets directed to the 'searchresults' page and the results are displayed.But on refreshing the page the search results are lost.How can I recover them using session?
The HTML code is:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" id='searchbox' placeholder="Search">
</div>
```

The js code is:

```
 Template.navigation.events({
    'submit form':function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var searchbox=document.getElementById('searchbox').value;
        Router.go('/posts/search/'+searchbox);
    }
    });

    Template.searchresults.helpers({
        'post':function(){
            var searchbox=document.getElementById('searchbox').value;
            var search=new RegExp('\\b'+searchbox+'\\b','i');
            return Posts.find({name:search});
        }
    });
```

and routerjs code is:

```
Router.route('/posts/search/:somesearch/',{
    template:'searchresults',
    name:'searchresults',


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a helper function, let's set the data context in your route:

```
Router.route('/posts/search/:somesearch/',{
  template:'searchresults',
  name:'searchresults',
  data: function(){
    return Posts.find({ name: this.params.somesearch });
  } 
});
```

Remove your `post` template helper entirely.

In your HTML template you'll need to iterate with `{{#each this}}` as `this` will be the *cursor* returned by the `data` function in the router.

Note, for multi-word searches and special characters you'll need to url-encode/decode the search string.

Comment: Sir I made the changes,but still on refreshing the page the content is lost.

Comment: Is your `#searchbox` getting populated on reload?

Comment: It seems to me that OP's main issue is due to the `searchresults` template using `#searchbox` value as parameter rather than the route's parameters. Therefore, re-populating the search box after action might already be too late.

Comment: Agreed. I'll rewrite the solution to have the router provide the data context.

Comment: Sir before going for helpers I was using data context in the route to return the searched posts.But I wasn't able to figure out the appropriate code for searchresults template so as to display the searched posts?What should I write under searchresults template?

Comment: In the router data function we use findOne.How can I get more than one post?

Comment: You can return a cursor from the data function and iterate over it with `{{#each this}}`

Comment: Thank you sir .Now it works fine even when I refresh the page.But please tell me why we used {{#each this}}?

Comment: Because the `data` function in the route established a _cursor_ as the value of the data context, i.e. `this` - then we had to iterate over it.

Comment: Why not {{#each data}}

Comment: Because the `data` function in i-r creates `this` by convention - it's not a template helper.